# how to change a value in a key-value inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to make it easier on myself so I can ask for a user input, while having it formatted nicely on one line, so I made this:   (IGNORE THE # LINES UNTIL THE PARAGRAPH BELOW)

```
1  vars = {'strt': ''}
2
3  def inp(decidvar, msg):
4#        (/\ 3 /\)  (/\1)
5
6#       ( \/ 1)
7    print(msg)
8
9#    (\/ 3 \/)  (\/ 2 \/)
10   decidvar = input('≥ ')
11
12   inp(vars['strt'], "do you want to learn the rules? (y/n)")
13#       (/\ 3 /\)            (/\   /\   1   /\   /\)
14
15   if vars['strt'] == 'y':
16     rules()
```

I am trying to make the console ask a question (1), ask for an input (2), and put the input in the variable in the key-value list (3) (so all the variables are in a single line), all in line 12. but the vars['strt'] thing stays equal to '' instead of 'y' or 'n'.

How could I fix this so it works like I want it to?

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers. If we want to copy and paste it, the line numbers get in the way.

Comment: okay. I won't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit global variable in the function, you must add this code into 1st function line

```
def abc(some_arg): 
    global vars
```